# What is the best verb for "undertaking an IPO"?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, collocations

There are many verbs to use here that I thought of as follows:

A company

- has an IPO
- conducts an IPO
- undertakes an IPO
- offers an IPO (redundant?)
- does an IPO
- initiates an IPO (sounds like it might not carry through)
- carries out an IPO

etc.

So far I thought that "undertakes an IPO" was best, but I am currently writing (translating) an article and it would be good to have more verbs for this than just "undertakes," and some of these verbs sound weird. Can anyone say what they think the best verb would be for this? Thanks.

Comment: You file paperwork with the SEC for an IPO. Often, one says: to file for an IPO. All this is visible at the SEC website. However, jornalistically, something else might be said. So, it depends on your actual, real context.

Comment: I see, but as a matter of fact I am actually writing about ICOs, Initial Coin Offerings, so it doesn't seem apt. I didn't realize there would be a difference between IPO and ICO. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

- A company **submits** an IPO.

The idea is that the company submits its offer to the consideration of any potential stockholders.

A google search shows around 18,300 hits for "submit an IPO".

Comment: That sounds quite nice to me, yes. However, I'm also interested in if we are speaking of the past, regarding a successful IPO that was carried out. Maybe "carried out" is good for that. Or, "completed."

Comment: Submit is not correct in financial terminology here.

Comment: Many of the search results are of the form "submit an IPO proposal" or "submit an IPO plan". It's not the same thing as "submit an IPO"...

Comment: I may have been misled by the collocation "submit an offer" (an IPO is an offer). Although there are some good examples of "submit an IPO", in finance it does seem to appear mostly as "submit an IPO filing/application".

Answer (score 1):

[Ngram suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=*_VERB+an+IPO&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) the five most common variations are:

> 1. **do** an IPO
> 2. **have** an IPO
> 3. **call** an IPO
> 4. **plan** an IPO
> 5. **make** an IPO.

but I am sure many other verbs are also fine, since something like "carry out" is essentially synonymous with "do".

The only one I would not use is "offer" because, as you say, *"to offer an initial public offering"* is redundant.  Of course that doesn't stop people from saying things like *"PIN number"* and *"ATM machine"* -- but you should do what you can, globally, to stamp out and eradicate redundancy in the world.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know anything about Ngram. What's the data set on that, or where can I get more information? Thx for your response also.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/info

Answer (score 0):

1) To issue an ICO, issue is used with IPO's and can be used for coins:

See this Bloomberg article: [iCO issue](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-09-18/what-s-an-ico-like-an-ipo-but-with-digital-coins-quicktake-q-a)

An IPO issuer or issue, by analogy, an ICO issue [noun] and issuer [company] issuing the coin offering.

"To avoid running afoul of the law, ICO issuers can try to establish a clear link between the rights attached to a token and its usage and performance on the blockchain platform."

2) To launch an ICO, alternatively, one can launch an ICO:

"Over the course of the last two weeks I have had over 10 companies directly contact me to help them launch an Initial Coin Offering “ICO”. Typically I ask: when do you want to launch? The most ridiculous answer I’ve received was: “next week”.

[launch an ICO](https://medium.com/blockchain-review/how-to-do-an-ico-d02c54a990c2)